# Swagger ApiListingResource is not recognized as a valid resource

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

I'm trying to integrate Swagger into my Jersey application following the guide they provide: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5

I'm using Jersy v1.17 and I'm using a custom application rather than `web.xml`

The following is everything I have in my simple test project which is failing!

```
public class ResConfig extends DefaultResourceConfig { // custom app
    public ResConfig() {
        super();
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:9998");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("test.resources"); // the package containing my resource
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

The simple resource I have

```
@Path("hello")
@Produces("application/json")
public class Res {
    public Res() {
    }


    @GET
    public Response getHello() {
        Result result = new Result(); // Result is annotated with XmlRootElement and contains one field String str;
        result.setStr("hello");
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

The main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ResConfig resConfig = new ResConfig();

    resConfig.getClasses().add(Res.class);
    resConfig.getClasses().add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resConfig.getClasses().add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

    GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:9998/", resConfig);

    System.in.read();
}
```

the POM contains the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Jersey Grizzly server fails on start by throwing exception:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.getListing(javax.ws.rs.core.Application,javax.servlet.ServletConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.getListing(javax.ws.rs.core.Application,javax.servlet.ServletConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String), annotated with GET of resource, class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: javax.servlet.ServletContext io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.context
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyServerFactory.java:243)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyServerFactory.java:137)
```

I searched the first 2 pages of Google for an answer but nothing helped!

Answer (score 0):

Swagger uses Servlet APIs, so the application MUST run in a servlet environment. The way you are configuring Grizzly does *not* set up a servlet container. It is only an HTTP server.

You want to use the `jersey-grizzly2-servlet` dependency instead, and use the `GrizzlyWebContainerFactory` to bootstrap the application. This will set up a servlet container.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();
initParams.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.package.ResConfig");
GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(uri, initParams);
```

Comment: well now the error also includes a class in Swagger:

`annotated with GET of resource, class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.AcceptHeaderApiListingResource, is not recognized as valid resource method`